# Is a URC (Uniform Resource Citation) synonymous with a Query String or Url Parameters?

Tags: http, networking, naming-standards, url, uri

Reading this:

https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/web/URI-URL-URN-IRI-URC

> URCs provide a set of attribute/value pairs that describe properties of URIs like authorship, publisher, copyright etc.

Is that synonymous with the query string found in here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?authorship=foo&publisher=bar&copyright=etc
```

namely, could

```
?authorship=foo&publisher=bar&copyright=etc
```

be considered the URC?

Comment: How is this unclear what I am asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather from Wikipedia's [Uniform Resource Characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Characteristic) article (and references in that article) that URCs are properties embedded (contained) within the specific resource.

So when you fetch a web page, for example, the page's URC might be embedded in the page using `<meta>` elements.

But URCs were never standardised/implemented (so they're not in fact *uniform*).